# Botão no centro da tela

Tags: html, css, div

Achei aqui a solução, caso alguem necessite

```
position:absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 200px;
```

Olá pessoal comecei uns teste novo aqui para uma aplicação, e estou com dificuldades de por o botão no centro da HTML via css, segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TESTE SCANIA</title>
     <!-- Aqui chamamos o nosso arquivo css externo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css\estilos.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <div id="teste">
    </div>
<form>
   <div id="botao">
      <input type="submit" name="INICIAR TESTE" value="INICIAR TESTE" class="botaoEnviar" />
   </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

e o css

```
body{
    background-color: #373435;
}

#teste{
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#botao{ text-align: absolute }
.botaoEnviar{
    width: 350px;
    text-align: absolute;
        left: 100%;
        top: 100%;
        margin-left:-110px;
        margin-top:-40px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #FCC302;
    font-size: 18px;

}
```

Comment: que você define por centro? horizontal, vertical, ou os dois?

Comment: ambos, seriam dois botões um alinhado do lado do outro no meio da tela tanto horizontal quanto vertical

Comment: consegui 
    position:absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 200px;

Comment: Felipe, poste sua solução como resposta no campo abaixo. Colocar na pergunta pode desorganizá-la.

Comment: @FelipeDeolindo Me parece que sua solução funcionará apenas no seu tamanho de janela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Position absolute` é uma propriedade estatica, não serve como parâmetro para centralizar conteúdo, assim em cada tela sua aplicação tera um tamanho diferente.

Use propriedade `relativas` exemplo

```css
body{
    background-color: #373435;
    height: 100%;
}
form{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.botaoEnviar{
    width: 350px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #FCC302;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="teste">
    </div>
<form>
      <input type="submit" name="INICIAR TESTE" value="INICIAR TESTE" class="botaoEnviar" />
</form>
</body>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: tentei amigo o seu código e ela ficou em baixo dessa imagem de background, no meio porem em baixo

Comment: Em form { flex-direction: column } troque por { flex-direction: row }

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também apenas usar as margens automáticas caso queira que seu elemento apenas centralize.

```
.classeOuElemento{ margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: entendi, mesmo assim obrigado mas no meu caso a pagina ficara off mesmo, em apenas uma tela, mas vou tentar usar sua solução pra ver